# PHP regex get Access Key

Tags: php, regex

Help me find php regex pattern to get access key in this string:

```
[INFO] [HBLEvents] The table predictionio_eventdata:events_17 doesn't exist 

yet. Creating now...

[INFO] [App$] Initialized Event Store for this app ID: 17.

[INFO] [App$] Created new app:

[INFO] [App$]       Name: shop456

[INFO] [App$]         ID: 17

[INFO] [App$] Access Key: 

X063irwHoRCEmOmWQSwY4kWaalkpxDqBzZWJnKfQDts6w1fhJOB0CSAAtTixNN05
```

Comment: is  char " part of content? hashcode is end of content?

Comment: no, it string quote, i edited. Key is end  of content

Answer (score 0):

> [INFO] [HBLEvents] The table predictionio_eventdata:events_17 doesn't
>   exist
>
> yet. Creating now...
>
> [INFO] [App$] Initialized Event Store for this app ID: 17.
>
> [INFO] [App$] Created new app:
>
> [INFO] [App$] Name: shop456
>
> [INFO] [App$] ID: 17
>
> [INFO] [App$] Access Key:
>
> X063irwHoRCEmOmWQSwY4kWaalkpxDqBzZWJnKfQDts6w1fhJOB0CSAAtTixNN05

```
preg_match('/Access Key:\n+(.*)$/s',$x,$m);
echo $m[1];
```

Comment: just add \n+ to skip new line chars

Answer (score 0):

You could use this: `Access Key:[\r\n]+([^ ]+)` with the `multiline` option enabled. An example is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/aB6kF6/2).